# How to draw an image of this function?

Tags: plotting

Define max {a, b, c} as the maximum value in a, b, and c.

How to draw an image of this function?

y=max {2 ^ x, 2x-3,6-x}

```
Plot[Max[2^x, 2 x - 3, 6 - x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

The correct image should look like this

[image]

[image]

How to make the x-axis cross the origin {0, 0}?

Comment: Check the document of `AxesOrigin`, and once again, please put more effort in reading the document: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHywM.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this does what you want.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**code**

```
ClearAll[x];
f = {2^x, 2 x - 3, 6 - x};
p1 = Plot[Max[f], {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red];
p2 = Plot[f, {x, -3, 10}, PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
   AxesLabel -> { TraditionalForm@HoldForm@x,  TraditionalForm@HoldForm@f[x]}];
Show[p2, p1, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 7}}, BaseStyle -> 14]
```

> How to make the x-axis cross the origin {0, 0}?

You do not need to use `AxesOrigin->` option to reproduce the same plot as you showed so I did not use it. I thought you asking just to reproduce the same image you have given.

Comment: Why do many times the x-axis of the function image drawn does not cross the origin {0,0}?

Comment: How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can adding this sentence solve the problem?```AxesLabel -> { TraditionalForm@HoldForm@x,  TraditionalForm@HoldForm@f[x]}```

Comment: **Why do many times the x-axis of the function image drawn does not cross the origin {0,0}?** sorry, I do not understand the question. If you mean you want to find if any of the functions listed in `f` above pass through origin? Then you can try `Solve` and see if you get solution. May be something like `Map[Solve[#==0,x,Reals]&,f]` which gives `{{},{{x->3/2}},{{x->6}}}` so no function passes through the origin.

Comment: **Can adding this sentence solve the problem?** what problem? This is meant to add the labels. Adding hold form just so that `f` does not evaluate and to print as `f` and not something else.